# How to add forms to a dictionary upon submission

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am creating a shopping cart as a part of the application I'm building.
I am trying to figure out how to add a form submission to a dictionary (I think this is what I need to do).
So for example this is what the page would look like(This is just test data).

[image: Cart]Upon Clicking the add button I want the item name and price to populate in the Orders table to the right of the Pricing table(To start off). Once all orders have been added I'd click the Order button and that will order the added items in some type of list to the database using sqlalchemy. Now I feel strongly and I may be wrong that upon submitting form using add button that the form needs to be added to a dictionary. I just don't know how to save that dictionary and where that dictionary should be stored? Here is my code as of now.

**routes.py**
I tried putting the dictionary with in the route function but a single instance is created on each submission. So nothing is really being saved to dictionary.

```
@app.route('/equipment', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def equipment():
    form = OrderEquipmentForm()
    eq = equipment_prices
    # Tried to store forms in this dictionary but it look like a new instance
    # is created on every form submission
    ordersss = {}

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        ordersss[form.Type.data] = form.Price.data
        print(form.Type.data, form.Price.data)
        print(ordersss)
        return redirect(url_for('equipment'))

    return render_template('equipment.html', name='equipment', eq=eq, form=form)

@app.route('/equipment/cart', methods=['GET, POST'])
def cart():
    return render_template('cart.html', name='cart')
```

**Forms.py**
Not sure if there needs to be function with in the actual form that adds the values to a dictionary

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class AddEquipmentForm(FlaskForm):
    Type = StringField('Type of Equipment',DataRequired())
    Price = StringField('Price',DataRequired())
    submit = SubmitField('Add equipment')

class OrderEquipmentForm(FlaskForm):

    Type = StringField()
    Price = StringField()
    Order = SubmitField('Order')

    # Should Dictionary go here?
    # Not sure
    def dict():
        dict = {}
        dict[Type] = Price
```

**equipment.html**
I would like to loop the element of the dictionary with in the Orders Table, if a dictionary is needed.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6-sm">
        <h1>Pricing</h1>
        <table class='border'>
          <thead class='border'>
            <th style="width:200px;">Equipment</th>
            <th style="width:200px; text-align:center;">Price</th>
            <th></th>
          </thead>
          {% for quip in eq %}
            <form method="post">
              {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
              <tr class ='border'>
                <td>{{ quip }}</td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"> <strong>${{ eq[quip] }}</strong></td>
                <!-- Here I'm adding StringFields from the form but hiding them so they aren't displayed so I can submit the data somehow, hopefully to a dictionary. -->
                <td style="display:none;">{{ form.Type(value=quip)}}</td>
                <td style="display:none;">{{ form.Price(value=eq[quip]) }}</td>
                <td><button class='btn btn-primary' type="submit">Add</button></td>
              </tr>
            </form>
          {% endfor %}
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6-sm">
        <h1>Orders</h1>
        <table>
          <!-- This is where a loop of the dictionary elements of the items added would go -->
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <button style='float:right' type="button" name="button" class='btn btn-info'>Order</button>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: with a flask web route everytime you click add it will re-render the page causing a browser refresh for your client. it is better to use Javascript and code this on the client side to build a JSON dictionary/object that will be finally passed to the server at the order point, not to mention this is standard web development practice and a better user experience - otherwise, you can still utilise flask web routes but  connect to them with AJAX through javascript so the user interface is smooth and continuous and doesnt rerender the page

Comment: Thank you I’ll try both options and see what works best! @Attack68